# How to fetch all the ids of checked present in a table

Tags: jquery

When i check All checkboxes and clcik the delete button , why it is not fetching the ids ??

But the same thing is working when i select somestatus under the drop down filter

http://jsfiddle.net/cdkLkcdk/19/

This is my code

```
   $(document).on('click', '#deletebtn', function(event ) {
  var $checked = $('#tablecontent').find(":checkbox:checked");

      if (!$checked.length) 
      {
        alert('Need to select atlease one checkbox button');
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        event.stopPropagation();
     }             
     else 
     {
        var ids = [];
        $.each($checked, function(i,e)
        {
          var status = $(e).parent().parent().find('.label-status').text();            
         if ($(e).attr("id") != 'selectall' && status == $('#filterstatus').val()) 
         {
            ids.push($(e).attr("id"))
         }          
      });        
     alert(ids);    
   }
});
```

Comment: You are getting ids "when i select somestatus..." because you have this `if ($(e).attr("id") != 'selectall' && status == $('#filterstatus').val())` in your code. When you remove this condition you will get ids, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/cdkLkcdk/21/)

Comment: what is filterstatus

Comment: There is a html element   <select id="filterstatus" >  , shown as status at the end of the table .

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in `filterstatus`, if you are not selecting anything there that condition is not handled

```
$(document).on('click', '#deletebtn', function (event) {
    var $checked = $('#tablecontent').find(":checkbox:checked").not('#selectall');

    var fstatus = $('#filterstatus').val();
    var ids = $checked.map(function () {
        var status = $(this).parent().parent().find('.label-status').text().trim();
        return !fstatus || fstatus == status ? this.id : undefined;
    }).get();

    if (ids.length) {
        alert('Need to select atlease one checkbox button');
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        event.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        alert(ids);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j1rzqk34/)

Answer (score 1):

I checked your jsFiddle. The issue is occurring in the `status == $('#filterstatus').val()` comparison you make.

I'm not sure where it's going wrong (checking the status value seems correct), but I changed this line to:

```
if ($(e).attr("id") != 'selectall' && !$(e).is(":hidden"))
```

And that does fix the problem.

Short explanation: instead of filtering on the selected value, I only take the elements that are visible ( = "not hidden", since only those with a correct status are visible at that point)